Factor-smooth interactions in generalized additive models
I have a very simple question regarding the continous factor-smooth interactions implement in the mgcv package in R: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/mgcv/html/factor.smooth.html
Reading the example provided by Gavin Simpson in https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/11/difference-splines-i/, it seems that these factor-smooth interactions can be used to model the effect of a continous covariate in different levels of a factor. Borrowing from Gavin's formulation: "... so you can fit a wiggly function in level foo and a smooth function in level bar, with each level’s function being learned from the data associated with that level.".
For me the above sounds suspiciously equivalent to simply splitting the data set based on the different factor levels and estimating a separate model for each of these. More concretely: Assume we are given some data set containing a continous variable x, response variable y and a factor z with levels "foo" and "bar". What would then be the difference between the two models fitted in the code below:
#first model based on using the by in gam()
model1 <- gam(y ~ s(x, by = z),
                  data = data,
                  family = gaussian(),
                  method = "REML")


#second model (simply two separate model for each factor level)
data1 <- data %>% filter(z == "foo")
data2 <- data %>% filter(z == "bar")

model2_1 <- gam(y ~ s(x),
                    data = data1,
                    family = gaussian(),
                    method = "REML")

model2_2 <- gam(y ~ s(x),
                    data = data2,
                    family = gaussian(),
                    method = "REML")



Correction based on Gavin's response:
As pointed out by Gavin model1 is wrong. The correct specification would include the parametric effect of z:
#first model based on using the by in gam()
model1 <- gam(y ~ z + s(x, by = z),
                  data = data,
                  family = gaussian(),
                  method = "REML")


The obvious difference would be that the two separate models wouldn't include the covariances between the two smooths. So there would be no way to statistically compare the two estimated smooths.
FYI: your model1 is wrong; you are missing the parametric effect of z for the group means.

Thank you Gavin! Would this difference also have implications for the predictive accuracy of the different models? Or is it only something that has an effect if one wishes to use the model for stastistical inference? I am asking because I obtain roughly the same model errors. And similar for the parametric effect of z: Is this necessary to include if the aim is only predictive accuracy? :)

If you're only interested in predictive accuracy then I doubt there'll be much difference between the models; there will be slight differences because in the by version, the basis for x is formed using all the values of x and the smooths share the basis expansion. In the separate models, the bases for x will use only the x values for the respective levels of z. And for model1 you need to include the parametric effect of z because otherwise the smooths of x have to also model the group means and $f(x)$ and they typically can't do both with no constant term in the basis.

Thanks a lot for this! I have corrected the post above to make it clear that model1 should include z parametrically. Along the way I would actually like to include the effect of other categorical variables in the model too. If I added a term like categorical_variable * z, am I right in assuming that this would automatically take care of the missing parametric effect of z? As I understand it the factor interaction above automatically creates the isolated levels of z.

The parametric f * z includes the main effects of each factor f and z so, yes, it includes the group means for z
